# Definición crontab para 2 días

Tags: cron

en una máquina Linux, en principio *CentOS* (pero debiera ser cualquiera), quiero realizar una tarea cron para incluir en el **crontab** que haga una ejecución que pase de un día para otro.

La ejecución que busco sería la siguiente:

```
01.01.2020 22:30 Hola Mundo
01.01.2020 23:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 00:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 01:30 Hola Mundo
--//--
02.01.2020 06:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 07:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 22:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 23:30 Hola Mundo
03.01.2020 00:30 Hola Mundo
...
```

Para alcanzarlo, trato de hacer esto:

```
30 22-8 * * * echo "Hola mundo"
```

Sin embargo, estoy encontrando un comportamiento justo al contrario (que por otra parte, entiendo):

```
01.01.2020 08:30 Hola Mundo
01.01.2020 09:30 Hola Mundo
01.01.2020 10:30 Hola Mundo
01.01.2020 11:30 Hola Mundo
--//--
01.01.2020 20:30 Hola Mundo
01.01.2020 21:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 08:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 09:30 Hola Mundo
02.01.2020 10:30 Hola Mundo
...
```

Resulta entendible y podría ser viable llevarlo a cabo de manera muy sencilla con dos lineas de crontab.

Pero en un desarrollo en el que estoy involucrado, no me sería posible llevarlo a cabo con dos líneas, forzosamente debería hacerse en una ¿eso sería posible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si, puedes unir varios rangos con una `,`, quedaria de esta manera:

```
30 22-23,0-7 * * * echo "Hola mundo"
```

He puesto que acabe a las 7 por que segun tu ejemplo la ultima hora de ejecucion era a las 7:30 y si en la definicion del crontab pones `0-8` la ultima ejecucion seria a las 8:30

Comment: Muy bueno si señor, no había caído en esa combinación. Muchisimas gracias!